# jQuery nth-child behaves erraticaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to get this code to work:

```
// Home status history handler
    $('div.rel-wrap table tr').on('click', function(){

// gets the relevid from the table
    var relevrow = $(this).closest('tr');

// assigns the id to a variable
    relevid = relevrow.children('th').text();

// fills the details panel
    $('#detalles span:eq(0)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('th').html());
    $('#detalles span:eq(1)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('td:nth-child(2)').text());   
    $('#detalles span:eq(2)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('td:nth-child(3)').text()); 
    $('#detalles span:eq(3)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('td:nth-child(4)').text());
    $('#detalles span:eq(4)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('td:nth-child(12)').text());
    $('#detalles span:eq(5)').html(' ' + relevrow.children('td:nth-child(13)').text());

detailspanelhandler('view', relevid);
});
```

I'm taking data from a table and doing stuff with the data that I get from it (with the function and such). That part works no problem.

However, what I'm also trying to do is show some of the data of the table in a separate panel below. The span:eq() correctly selects the span where the desired text has to be, and nth-children 2 to 4 display correctly. But once I get to 12 and 13 (the jump is on purpose, I'm not leaving out code there), the nth-child pseudo-selector starts behaving erratically.

If I do...

```
console.log(relevrow.children('td:nth-child(12)').text());
console.log(relevrow.children('td:nth-child(13)').text());
```

...it displays the correct information in the console. But when I try to assign it to the span via the .html (as seen above), it doesn't display that information. Instead it displays what seems to be a random selection. For example, if I assign the nth-child(12) to two of the spans, one shows one thing, and the other one shows another. And it's the same nth-child! But in the console, it's all A-OK, the right data every time.

Any ideas on what could be messing up my code? I can't seem to find a pattern to debug.

Something worth noting is that, whatever data the span ends up showing, it's always the same on each click and on refresh. Whatever data it chooses to choose from the nth-child selector is always the same. Only I cannot see or predict where it will come from.

If I'm not being clear on something, feel free to ask me for clarification. This is my first question here, please go easy on me! =)

**[EDIT]:** Heres a jsfiddle with the bug. Check the console to see the inconsistency!

https://jsfiddle.net/q5m0cnLu/14/

Comment: Please set up a [mcve], including the HTML necessary to see what your code actually does.

Comment: So you got `th` and `td` elements inside one row? Then don't confuse `td:nth-child` with the n-th `td` element ...

Comment: Oh... well, that will take some time to reproduce... I'm working on a very complex system. It will be very hard for me to come up with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I'll work on it though. Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know that was required!

Each <tr> has a <th> and <td>s inside. In my case, the data I'm looking for is in the <td>s (and on the <th>, but that one is retrieved correctly).

What's the difference between the nth-child and the n-th td element? So far in other parts of the code I have been using it interchangeably with good results!

Comment: Code of your table, and what #detalles contains should basically do, no? Copy&paste those two from the source code view in the browser, add above code - which seems pretty self-contained, apart from what the unknown `detailspanelhandler` function might do - if you throw that into a jsfiddle or codepen and add jQuery, you should only be a few tweaks away from a run-able example that helps us reproduce what's going on.

Comment: Where is `#detalles` in relation to `div.rel-wrap table`, is it inside that same table? It sounds as if adding the new content to `#detalles` is altering the `td:nth-child` indexing for the subsequent lookup.

Comment: @CBroe I've added the jsfiddle and reproduced the error!

Comment: @stovroz It seems to be something along those lines, but I can't figure out what or how. Check the jsfiddle in the edit for clarification!

Comment: There’s only five spans inside #detalles, yet you are trying to access 0 to 5? I get `Contacto: Hay llaves` in the last one, if I add another row with text `Extra:`, then that results in `Extra: eHay llaves en sucursal` ...

Comment: Jesus, I am an idiot... I switched from `nth-child()` to `eq()` right before I started doing this, I added the 0 index, as is needed for `eq()`, and I forgot to remove the last one. Thanks a lot @CBroe, that fixed it, and sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid issue... I really thought it was something more complex than that.

Comment: How do I mark the question as answered? (There is no end to my incompetence)

Comment: You can only mark an actual answer as the solution to your problem. I’ve added one, although it is rather short (not the “preferred” kind of answer, but there isn’t that much more to say on the issue now either) - so feel free to accept that, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were only five `span` elements inside `#detalles`, yet the script tried to access `0` to `5` via `:eq()`.

Turned out to be a simple mistake introduced while modifying existing code.